# What could be the reason of this error when using date time in Python?

Tags: python, pandas, csv, datetime

I use Spyder with Python 3 for data analysis. I am reading date and time columns from a CSV file. The file contains the the columns for date and time as shown below:

```
04-09-20,16:32:56
04-09-20,16:32:57
04-09-20,16:32:58
```

So I have a date(in 04-09-20 format) and a time array in(16:32:56) format. To use the data and time together in a plot's axis I first combine these date and time arrays and then use pd.to_datetime() as follows:

```
date_combine_time = date + ' ' + t

date_time = pd.to_datetime(date_combine_time, format = "%d-%m-%Y %H:%M:%S")

plt.plot(date_time, values)
```

But I get the following error:

> time data '04-09-20 16:32:56' does not match format '%d-%m-%Y
>   %H:%M:%S' (match)

What could be wrong here?

Comment: You might be looking for `%y`, instead of `%Y` Check the [strftime format codes](https://docs.python.org/3/library/datetime.html#strftime-and-strptime-format-codes)

Comment: %Y is year with four digits

Comment: This works for me: `datetime.strptime("04-09-20,16:32:56", "%d-%m-%y,%H:%M:%S")`. Should be the same for `pd.to_datetime`.

Answer (score 2):

`%Y` is for 4 digit years. You need 2 digit years, which is `%y`. This means your format should change to `"%d-%m-%y,%H:%M:%S"`. I also added the missing comma `,`, since your date strings need to match the format exactly.

You can have a look at the [Format Codes](https://docs.python.org/3.8/library/datetime.html#strftime-and-strptime-format-codes) if you are unsure.